# PHP ganon how to read javascript

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I am scraping some html pages using php ganon dom parser but i am stuck where i need to read some javascript from the source my javascript is like.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        ig_lightbox_main_img=0;
ig_lightbox_img_sequence.push('http://someimageurl.com/image.jpg');
ig_lightbox_img_labels.push("Some text");
ig_lightbox_img_sequence.push('http://someimageurl.com/image2.jpg');
ig_lightbox_img_labels.push("Some text 2");
    });
</script>
```

I want to read the url form the above script which is coming with html of page i have used this code for now

```
$html = str_get_dom('some page html here');
     foreach($html('.product-img-box script[type=text/javascript]') as $script){
     echo $script->html();
}
```

But this is not working. Any idea on how to read script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with quotes around `type=text/javascript` in the string to the `$html` object.

I had a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/#Modification) and they have an example:

```
foreach($html('a[href ^= "http://"]') as $element) {
    $element->wrap('center');
}
```

I think it was the `/` that may have made it return the wrong result.

**EDIT**

Was confused by the question before, I thought the issue was that you couldn't get the data inside the script and it was because of your selector. Anyway, after a bit of thinking, if you have a string copy of the script tag with data inside, just run a regular expression over it.

Here is an example that I tested:

```
$string = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        ig_lightbox_main_img=0;
ig_lightbox_img_sequence.push('http://someimageurl.com/image.jpg');
ig_lightbox_img_labels.push(\"Some text\");
ig_lightbox_img_sequence.push('http://someimageurl.com/image2.jpg');
ig_lightbox_img_labels.push(\"Some text 2\");
    });
</script>";

$regex = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/";

$results = array();

preg_match_all($regex,$string,$results);

var_dump($results);
//Result: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(33) "http://someimageurl.com/image.jpg" [1]=> string(34) "http://someimageurl.com/image2.jpg" } }
```

`$results` has the URL data inside of it as returned from `preg_match_all` ([Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)).

If it helps, once you have the URL, you can use `parse_url` ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)) in PHP which will split the string URL into something easier to work with.

**Note: The regular expression used is quite a simple expression and won't cover every case. As stated [here](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html), it is very difficult to get a perfect regular expression for this.**

Comment: I want read http from ig_lightbox_img_sequence.push('http://someimageurl.com/image2.jpg'); how $html('a[href ^= "http://"]') this selector going to work on this...??

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, your selector is fine beyond my suggestion of adding `"` around the `text/javascript` part of it. So like: `.product-img-box script[type="text/javascript"]`, give that a shot?

Comment: Is it just not finding anything to iterate over?

Comment: Its reading all script tag coming under the .product-img-box  div but i want to get only the script tag and its contents that i have posted in my question

Comment: Sorry, was confused by the question, updated answer to reflect new findings. In short, a carefully coded regular expression should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a ton man you solved the problem you are the hero.. :-) Thanks will voteup you when i got 15 up points.